# Unable to install octave-forge Miscellaneous package in Octave 3.8 Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, package, octave

I'm new to Octave, attempting to install package 'miscellaneous' to use GNU Units. Installation fails. I tried:

> apt-get install octave-miscellaneous

The deb package installs, but is not listed in Octave 3.8 (via >>pkg list). Then I tried:

```
> pkg install -forge miscellaneous
```

Octave 3.8 responds:

```
error: element number 1 undefined in return list
error: called from:
error:   /opt/octave3.8/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/get_forge_pkg.m at line 40, column 14
error:   /opt/octave3.8/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/get_forge_download.m at line 26, column 12
```

I've searched quite a bit and have not found what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the error message, and the location from where the error is throw, this comes from a problem reading the page of the miscellaneous package. The weird error message is because of [this bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?41260).

So make sure Octave is able to use `urlread` (try with some random file you know it exists), and that you didn't made any typo when entering the package name.

Finally, you should not be mixing Octave packages installed via the Debian repositories and installed via Octave's `pkg`.

Comment: Octave 3.8 was new enough that I did not originally want to depend on it. Moving Octave 3.8 to /opt/octave worked and will reduce likelihood of future issues.

Comment: @ndemarco what? I didn't say there's any problem with the choice of `/opt`. Actually, that should make no difference at all. Did you follow the link for the bug report and read the first comment of it. Make sure you made no typo when writing miscellaneous. The error message you got suggests the same problem (a regression in `urlread` when it fails to read a page and there's two output arguments).

Comment: I was super green with Linux when I asked this. Now the question seems pretty straightforward. It was, as you suggested, a problem with 'urlread'

Answer (score 0):

This is because your System's Octave installed by default is not the latest (3.8), but octaves own package manager tries to load.

```
apt-get install octave-miscellaneous
```

Installs to a different prefix, compared to your /opt/octave3.8, which you probably compiled your self.

[Here](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/octave-miscellaneous/filelist), you can see where the files are installed.

The solution would be to install the miscellaneous packages yourself. Note, that you will probably need to run octave as root for the installation, or give your user write permissions to `/opt/octave3.8/share` ...

Answer (score -1):

For anyone coming from RHEL/Centos/Fedora distributions, use:

```
dnf search octave-miscellaneous
dnf install -y octave-miscellaneous
```