# installing miscellaneous in Octave- need GNU units

Tags: installation, octave, gnu

I'm trying to install miscellaneous in Octave, but it says GNU units is required. I can't figure out how to install it, and none of the existing pages on this issue have been helpful. I have Octave 4.0. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383753/unable-to-install-octave-forge-miscellaneous-package-in-octave-3-8-ubuntu) says I may have to install miscellaneous myself, but I'm not sure how to do that or what that even means. Here is the error I get:

```
>> pkg install -forge miscellaneous
configure: error: The program GNU Units is required to install Octave-Forge miscellaneous package.
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking term.h usability... yes
checking term.h presence... yes
checking for term.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for units... no

pkg: error running the configure script for miscellaneous.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file /usr/share/octave/4.0.0/m/pkg/private/configure_make.m near line 79, column 9
```

Comment: Install units, for example on ubuntu "apt-get install units"

Comment: THANK YOU! I had tried that but I may not have re-opened Octave.